# Having a Jasper Reports field appear under certain conditions

Tags: jasper-reports, report, odoo

My field currently appears only when the quotation in OpenERP is set as progress, however I also need it to be able to appear when if it is also registered as "sent" or as "draft"

My current Print When Expression is as follows

```
$F{Estado-state}.equals("progress") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

I tried using OR pipes to have progress, sent, and draft inside the parenthesis but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling with OR pipes I got it working.

```
$F{Estado-state}.equals( "progress" ) || $F{Estado-state}.equals( "sent" ) || $F{Estado-state}.equals( "draft" ) ||   ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

This worked without any issues.